# How to get around network mapping issue "Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated"

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a Jenkins docker container by following this [page](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/how-to-install-and-run-jenkins-with-docker-compose) so I can test locally. Problem is with this is that once I've ran `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts` it seems I cannot use the same port for my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    user: root
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
        - .jenkins/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

The error shown in PowerShell (I'm on windows 10 if that's relevant) is:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint jenkins (xxxx): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

I've made sure it's not affected from another container, image or volume and have deleted everything apart from this.

I wish to use Jenkins locally but how can I get around this? I'm not familiar with networking and what I've googled so far has not seemed to work for me. I would like this to be able to use Jenkins ui on `localhost:8080`

Comment: Did you stop the running container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If port 8080 is already allocated on your host machine, you can just map a different one to 8080 of the container instead. Two things can't be mapped to the same port on the host machine. In order to map 8081 for example, change your compose to the following:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    user: root
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 8081:8080 # a different port is mapped here
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
        - .jenkins/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Then, you just need to access the container started by `docker-compose` with port `localhost:8081` rather than `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Awesome! This works, I'm able to access the jenkins ui